# The Strange World of Question asking at the Mathematics Stack Exchange (MSE).

Tags: discussion

Please let me introduce myself.

My name is Mr. Sarn Ursell, and, recently, -I had actually posted a question here at the Mathematics Stack Exchange, and yet it got blocked.

And, -this seems strange to me, as I thought that this Mathematics Stack Exchange was supposed to be a place in which you learn, along with Universities all around the world.

Look, don't get me wrong, please, I am not criticizing the Mathematics Stack Exchange (MSE), but I really am unsure as to how to post a good question, and which is a legal//illegal option, and which is not..., ...-and I really only asked the question in the first instance, because I am desperate to find help with some projects in Mathematica which I would like to do.

I have looked everywhere, but all to no avail with help on my projects on audio and images.

Where can I get help with these questions I do wonder to myself...

Is it a legal option to ask people on the Mathematics Stack Exchange to contact//E-Mail you privately to share ideas, I wonder also.

I do not know.

Please reply and we will talk about the matter.

Regards,

Mr. Sarn Ursell.

Comment: math.se is basically a database of maths questions. If you want to ask a maths question, math.se is the place to do it. However, you say that you want to  "find help with some projects in Mathematica which I would like to do." So maybe a more suitable place to to this would be the forums on mathematica : https://community.wolfram.com/content?curTag=mathematica would be more appropriate. There's also a mathematica.se: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: "I really am unsure as to how to post a good question...."  Maybe this will help: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: I presume you must have looked up the Mathematica Stack exchange as well. Your question will be a cent-percent  well received if it is well written and has context, as long as it is within the type of questions that can be addressed on MSE.

Comment: Yes, indeed.They have treated me quite fairly...I found.

Comment: @ursellsarn Happy to know that, hope your experience on the website will be better with your understanding of MSE enhanced.

Comment: I still need someone who can communicate with me perhaps privately on some projects a one-to-one "friendship" type basis. Is it against the policy of the MSE to request such things/these things? Is it OK/alright that I do this? Please advise.